# File `ieeetran.sty' not found - trying to use IEEE bibliography style with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am trying to use IEEE bibliography style with LaTeX. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and I thought it would be as easy as all of the other packages, just install from the manager and then `\usepackage{ieeetran}` and then `\bibliography{ieeetran}`
I'm quite new to this, to be honest I don't even know the proper name to put in the curly brackets and it's not obvious from some of the documentation. Please let me know what other information you might need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot load the `IEEEtran` package as the installation through the MikTeX package manager doesn't contain a style package (see list of files under properties in manager entry).

As suggested in the [IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf), the following command lines may be used at your bibliography,

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
```

where the former command is to inform LaTeX to change the bibliography style to `IEEEtran` and the latter command may be used to input the file name(s) of your `.bib` file.